# Opencv .at method not working as intended?

Tags: opencv, mat

trying to perform some easy conversions to get my camera poses in more manageable coordinates and I keep running into one issue:

```
    vector< Mat> newpoints; 

    Mat oldpoint =  Mat::zeros(4,1, CV_32F);

    oldpoint.at<float>(3,0) = 1.0;

    Mat translation = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_32F);
    Mat rotation = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_32F);
    Mat tmp_rot = Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_32F);
    Mat trans;
    Mat rota;

cout << "rearranging coords" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < tvecs.size(); i++){
    trans = tvecs[i];
    rota = rvecs[i];

    translation.at<float>(0,0) = 1.0;
    translation.at<float>(1,1) = 1.0;
    translation.at<float>(2,2) = 1.0;
    translation.at<float>(3,3) = 1.0;

    translation.at<float>(0,3) = trans.at<float>(0);
    translation.at<float>(1,3) = trans.at<float>(1);
    translation.at<float>(2,3) = trans.at<float>(2);

    Rodrigues(rota, tmp_rot);

    rotation.at<float>(0,0) = tmp_rot.at<float>(0,0);
    rotation.at<float>(0,1) = tmp_rot.at<float>(0,1);
    rotation.at<float>(0,2) = tmp_rot.at<float>(0,2);
    rotation.at<float>(1,0) = tmp_rot.at<float>(1,0);
    rotation.at<float>(1,1) = tmp_rot.at<float>(1,1);
    rotation.at<float>(1,2) = tmp_rot.at<float>(1,2);
    rotation.at<float>(2,0) = tmp_rot.at<float>(2,0);
    rotation.at<float>(2,1) = tmp_rot.at<float>(2,1);
    rotation.at<float>(2,2) = tmp_rot.at<float>(2,2);
    rotation.at<float>(3,3) = 1.0;
}
```

The value assignments inside the for, when I'm using the .at on the right side make no sense. They are completely different values from the ones in the original matrix.

Comment: please check tmp_rot.depth() or tmp_rot.type(). I guess it is double instead of float so try tmp_rot.at<double> everywhere

Comment: That was it. 
Changed "trans = tvecs[i]; rota = rvecs[i];" to tvecs[i].convertTo(trans, CV_32F);
rvecs[i].convertTo(rota, CV_32F);

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Micha pointed out, there was a type mismatch.

Fixed by:

```
    tvecs[i].convertTo(trans, CV_32F);
    rvecs[i].convertTo(rota, CV_32F);
    //trans = tvecs[i];
    //rota = rvecs[i];
```